# Prism.js highlighter not escaping code, even with plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

According to the Prism.js docs here: http://prismjs.com/plugins/unescaped-markup/

Using this plugin (I checked it to include in the JS download) I am supposed to be able to use html code in my code block without having to escape the tags.

But the code just renders, without showing the tags.

Following one of the methods, I tried using

```
<pre class="line-numbers">
 <code class="language-html"><!--
   <h1>Heading 1</h1>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amcia atque voluptatum repellat.</p>
  --></code>
</pre>
```

But then nothing shows in the code block at all.

Without the comment tags, I just get the rendered html:
[image]

I am calling this in my angular js 1.4.9 controller:

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.ds.badges').controller('BadgesController', function ($log) {
    var _this = this;

    _this.tester = 'foo';
    Prism.highlightAll();
  });
})();
```